# What is the "Ember Way" to fetch, parse and associate related models from 2 different non-REST data sources

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 models in my project, `Ticker` and `Option`.  A `Ticker` `hasMany` `Options`.  A Ticker is  financial information about a stock (bid, ask, P/E ratio, etc...), and also contains many financial Options.

Models:

```
var Ticker = DS.Model.extend({
  symbol: DS.attr('string'),
  options: DS.hasMany('option'),
  Ask: DS.attr('string'),
  AverageDailyVolume: DS.attr('string'),
  Bid: DS.attr('string')
});

var Option = DS.Model.extend({
  ticker: DS.belongsTo('ticker'),
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  strikePrice: DS.attr('string'),
  lastPrice: DS.attr('string'),
  change: DS.attr('string'),
  changeDir: DS.attr('string'),
  bid: DS.attr('string'),
  ask: DS.attr('string'),
  vol: DS.attr('string'),
  openInt: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

The urls I'm using for both resources are:

Ticker data url: [http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%27amzn%27)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%27amzn%27%29&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env)

Options data url: [http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.options%20WHERE%20%20symbol%3D%27amzn%27&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.options%20WHERE%20%20symbol=%27amzn%27&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=)

Neither are REST resources so I'm extending RESTAdapters and JSONSerializers to fetch the JSON and parse it into the format Ember-Data wants.

The flow the my app:

1. User inputs ticker symbol which is passed to TickerRoute in params.
2. `TickerRoute.setupController()` calls `this.store.find('ticker', ticker_symbol);` to get the Ticker data
3. `TickerAdapter.find()` Builds the url based on the ticker_id (the stock symbol) and fetches the JSON from yahoo and returns it.
4. `TickerSerializer.extractSingle()` parses the JSON into a format Ember-Data is expecting.

My question:
**In which step, and how do I get my Option data and associate it to the Ticker?**

What I've tried to do so far

- In `TickerAdapter.find()` call `store.findAll('option', ???)`.  But this only takes a 'type', not an id.  Because my data source isn't REST, I can't get an array of options by going to http://query.yahooapis.com/AAPL/options I need the specific ticker id to build the url to get my data.
- In `TickerAdapter.find()` call `store.find('option', ticker_id)`.  But when I return an array of Options, Ember-Data's `extractSingle()` method, strips out the "non-primary" records and I end up with only 1 Option in my array (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/573798346516372657824a49a8d11bc6343529bf/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L308)
- In `TickerAdapter.find()` use `$.getJSON` to fetch Option data and do all the parsing within the TickerSerializer.  This is ghetto.

If the RESTAdapter findAll() method could take an id as a parameter, I think I'd be fine.

I'm betting there's an "Ember Way" to do this, I just can't see it.

Comment: You're never actually saving anythin" back to that api are you?

Comment: @kingpin2k Nope, read only

Comment: Honestly I'd create a custom adapter and use POJOs, or create Ember Objects.  Is there any particular reason you're using Ember Data?

Comment: I'm going to have 20+ of these in my app and think ember-data is the easiest way to scale up to that.